# Flutter string fixes

Tags: flutter, dart

Maybe someone can help with advice. I need to change the string ''šķļī" to "skli" in flutter for search. For example, if the string contains "ŠODIEN" I need to fix it to "SODIEN" or "ŠOKOLĀDE" to "SOKOLADE".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to translate one language to another then you can use [translate](https://pub.dev/packages/translator) package.

But if you want to convert it manually, then you can use this. Just make sure you added all the special characters in the switch case you want to convert.

```
void main() {
  print(getNewString("šķļī"));
  print(getNewString("ŠOKOLĀDE"));
}

String getNewString(String s){
 String newString = "";
  s.split('').forEach((a){
    switch(a){
      case "Š":
        newString += "S";
        break;
      case "Ā":
        newString += "A";
        break;
      case "š":
        newString += "s";
        break;
      case "ķ":
        newString += "k";
        break;
      case "ļ":
        newString += "l";
        break;
      case "ī":
        newString += "i";
        break;
      default:
        newString += a;
        break;
    }
  });
    return newString;
}
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks for a fast answer! I just tested and your code works exactly as I wanted.